# Data structure for storing and working with XML element's attributes

Tags: java

I am parsing an XML file and building a tree internally. This is a GUI editor for our XML format that will allow users to easily modify the XML files without having to actually go into the raw data. It also provides various functionality for our data.

Each element in the XML file will correspond to a node on the tree, but now I'm thinking about how I should store the attributes so that I can

1. Display them in a table
2. Modify their values

I've thought of using a HashMap, where the keys are the attribute name and the values are the corresponding value of that attribute. So for example, I might have something like

```
myattrs.put("Attr1", ... );
myattrs.put("Attr2", ... );
myattrs.put("Attr3", ... );
```

However, I would also like the display them in a certain order. This isn't really a problem either: I could have an array specify this order, and use it to populate a table.

```
return new String[] { "Attr3", "Attr1", "Attr2" }
```

However, this design means I am hardcoding the keys.

Is there another way that I can store the attributes so that I can quickly look them up, display them in a certain order, and also be able to modify the value associated with that attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`. The keys order will be preserved.

However it seems you are on the wrong way. XML is an hierarchical structure that is typically presented as a tree. I do not know how are you parsing XML but if you are using DOM you actually do not need other model. DOM (Document Object Model) provides you a standard and very well known way to parse and model the XML document.

But wait a moment. Using DOM directly you are going forward from 19th century (I am sorry) where you are now to the end of the 20th century. But check your calendar. It is 2013 now. Take a look on JAXB or probably other higher level tools that make your life easier. Good luck.

Do not hesitate to ask questions on your way.

Comment: I am using SAX to parse it.

Comment: DOM is implemented on top of SAX. It already implements what you are trying to do - model.